# How Does Garlic Ward Away Negative Spirits?

Tags: tisha-bav, cemetery-grave

The [Taamei Haminhagim (659)](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14556&st=&pgnum=306&hilite=) quotes the Shaar Hamelech who says:

> טעם שבט״ב מטילין שום על בית הקברות, לפי ששום מבריח החיצונים, ובכל ימות
> השנה,יכולין לינצל ע״י תורה ותפלה ואין לחם אחיזה - The reason why on Tisha B'Av people hang garlic by the cemetery is because it wards away the "chitzonim." The rest of the year one can overcome and prevent them from grabbing hold through learning Torah and davening."

What is special about garlic that it wards off these negative forces? (Perhaps this is where the nations' idea of using garlic to scare away vampires comes from.)

Comment: The nations taking it from us is definitely one possible direction of transmission...

Comment: We find that ruach ra settles on open garlic overnight. Perhaps they have a connection to garlic that draws them, and keeps them away from people. In Kabbalah there’s an idea that when Ben Azzai said everyone is like klipas hashum, he was referring to taking souls and making them pure, and he used garlic as the metaphor

Comment: See Shaar Hagilgulim perek 34:4